# How to get random effects in lmer on mice-object

Tags: lme4, r-mice

I imputed 50 datasets with mice. Now I want to run a multilevel regression and pool the results over the 50 datasets.
My mids object is called new_imp04

```
KA_Geschlecht_01 <- with(new_imp04,
                         lme4::lmer(s1uka ~ 
                              c_trs1sex + 
                              g_trs1sex + c_s1udi  + 
                              (1|Lerngr), 
                      REML = FALSE))

KA_Geschlecht_01_p <- pool(KA_Geschlecht_01)
KA_Geschlecht_01_p
summary((KA_Geschlecht_01_p))
```

When I run the model on one dataset the output contains information about random effects and fixed effects. The output for the pooled results looks different and I see the intercept and fixed effects. How can I get the pooled results for what is named random effects: Std.Dev. of Intercept and Resiudal when I run lmer on a single data set.

[image: one dataset output]
[image: pooled output]